# How do you change a drop down menu to work with touch screens?

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to figure out where in HTML5 or what this is called but I want to change my drop downs into interactive selections like you see for android to make it easier for users.

A normal bootstrap style select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="content" >
   <option value="0">selection A</option>
   <option value="1">selection B</option>
   <option value="2">selection C</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to do with it.  I am not sure what it is called and it seems hard to find or figure out yet you see it in a lot of places.  Is it an HTML5 feature?

[image]

Comment: Android has something similar to that which enhances HTML `select` elements so that they take up the entire screen. [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uHFov.png) is what it looks like by default, no styling necessary (and [here's](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select) the code if you want to see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little googling for you

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_form_select.asp

Comment: I see, so on some browsers it shows it as scrolling and on other browsers it shows as radio buttons... Great!

Comment: When you view the site from an Android device's browser, it will show a list. When you view the site from an Iphone device's browser, it will show a Scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends upon your device. This will varies upon device to device. I have tested it on multiple handsets with from different manufacturers.